# stanford segmenter for Chinese and the Priority of my custom dictionary

Tags: machine-learning, stanford-nlp

I am recently using stanford segmenter for Chinese segmentation. And now I have a question: Some of the segmentation results don't follow  my custom dictionary completely, such as "桃子的爱情" cut into "桃子" "的" "爱情" ,  "58同城" cut into "58" "同城" and so on.   "桃子的爱情" and  "58同城" are both in my custom dictionary. I want  "桃子的爱情" and  "58同城" to be  independent words.
    Does the segmenter have the interface to  split words according to my custom dictionary  first? Thank you.